# Front end html/css themes for python/django programming

Tags: python, django, frontend

Are there some frontend/skeleton-like html templates with a nice web2 flavor ready to be used with python/django?

I know it could be any html and probably nothing specifically for python/django, but my question is, maybe the python/django community is using something in contrib already available in this sense ... something to have a nice output in terms of html/css, 
for example similar to the nice html/css output of Databrowse contrib module. (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/databrowse/)

Another example in this sense: many are using sphinx for documentation, that is giving a 
"common and nice" look and feel to the frontend compared with raw html. So, something like that but not for docs, for data :)

I hope the question is clear, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for ways to *design* the web page, so the answer is in the CSS field.

I like the [YAML CSS framework](http://www.yaml.de). Needs a bit of reading, but is very flexible.

Comment: Thanks Jammon, I'm going to take a look at it :)

Comment: thanks tamizhgeek, yes, I saw the yaml builder and it's very useful : )

Answer (score 0):

[Blue print CSS](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) is a another framework which you can use. It very simple than YAML one.

And have a look at [YAML builder](http://builder.yaml.de/) - this is browser based GUI tool to build web page design. You just drag and drop stuff like you do in any desktop GUI builder and the builder will generate CSS for that!